# How can I take a few paragraphs of text, see if any sentence has a pronoun and select all those sentences to make a new paragraph?

Tags: python, nltk

1. Should I use NLTK or regular expressions to split it?
2. How can I do the selection for pronouns (he/she). I want to select any sentence that has a pronoun.

This is a part of a larger project and I am new to Python. Could you please point me to any helpful code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a NLP project which has similar needs. I suggest you to use **NLTK** since it makes things really easy and gives us a lot of flexibility. Since you need to collect all sentences having pronouns, you can split all sentences in the text and hold them in a list. Then, you can iterate over the list and look for sentences containing pronouns. Also make sure you note down the index of the sentence (in the list) or you can form a new list.

**Sample code below:**

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

sentences = ['alice loves to read crime novels.', 'she also loves to play chess with him']
sentences_with_pronouns = []

for sentence in sentences:
    words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    for word in words:
        word_pos = pos_tag([word])
        if word_pos[0][1] == 'PRP':
            sentences_with_pronouns.append(sentence)
            break

print sentences_with_pronouns
```

**Output:**

```
['she also loves to play chess.']
```

**P.S.** Also check [pylucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) and [whoosh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh) libraries which are pretty useful NLP python 
packages.

Comment: This is broken for the case when you have sentences with more than one pronoun: ['she also loves to play chess with him.'] -> ['she also loves to play chess with him.', 'she also loves to play chess with him.'].

Comment: Thanks for notifying!. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

NLTK is your best bet. Given a string of sentences as input, you can obtain a list of those sentences containing pronouns by doing:

```
from nltk import pos_tag, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
paragraph = "This is a sentence with no pronouns. Take it or leave it."
print [sentence for sentence in sent_tokenize(paragraph)
       if 'PRP' in {pos for _,pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))}]
```

Returns:

```
['Take it or leave it.']
```

Basically we split the string into a list of sentences, those sentences into a list of words and convert the list of words for each sentence into a *set* of part of speech tags (this is important since if we don't, when we have multiple pronouns in a sentence, we would get get duplicate sentences).